# Selecting distinct column of a distinct column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to select just 2 distinct column to determine the records that are shown in my query. The column userid is capable of owning several houses which mean userid can be present multiple times currently. However, I only care if they specific colors of a house, so I'd like the userid column to be distinct, along with the House colum while the rest of the rows can remain to be whatever is within that row.

```
Select UserID, House, NumOfPpl, NumOfCars 
from people
```

Results:

```
userID  House  NumOfPpl  NumOfCars 
-----------------------------------
1a        red    3          2
1a        blue   1          1
1a        red    5          4
1a        green  2          3
1a        blue   1          3
2a        red    3          3
3a        green  4          6
3ab       red    2          1
3ab       red    5          5
3ab       blue   2          1
```

Would need to be:

```
userID  House  NumOfPpl  NumOfCars
----------------------------------
1a        red    3          2
1a        blue   1          1
1a        green  2          3
2a        red    3          3
3a        green  4          6
3ab       red    2          1
3ab       blue   2          1
```

I have used cte to get rid of duplicate userid's, but how can I get rid of duplicate house's, within userid's?

```
 ;with cte AS (
    select userid, 
    house, 
    numofppl, 
    numofcars, 
    row_number() OVER(partition by userID order by house) AS rowcounter
    FROM people
)

SELECT userid, house, numofppl, numofcars
from cte 
WHERE rowcounter = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried using groupby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the values in the `partition by` that you want to be unique.  So, I think you want `userID, house` there.  The `order by` doesn't make a difference:

```
with cte AS (
    select p.* 
           row_number() over (partition by userID, house order by house) AS seqnum
    from people p
)

select userid, house, numofppl, numofcars
from cte 
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: 5 star answer! Thank you so much. I was unaware a partition could contain multiple values!

Answer (score 0):

This query would work.

> SELECT * FROM people
>   WHERE house = ANY (SELECT DISTINCT house FROM people);

Try this i guess this should work.